# Fluid simulation flows through effector

Tags: fluid-simulation, mantaflow

[image: I definitely have Use Effector on.]

[image]

My first issue, was that the particles got nowhere near the mesh. Increasing the resolution divisions seemed to work. But, everything now flows through my object. Trying a whole new setup, works - the objects collide. Maybe the mesh here is weird? I have not a clue.

Comment: Have you recalculated the simulation (Cache > Type > Replay)?

Comment: provide blend file, so we can check it out...but i am pretty sure it is your resolution...

Comment: @moonboots It is set on replay. I've also just re-selected it, and run the simulation again - but no luck

Comment: Yes you need to reselect to relaunch a calculation, but it doesn't seem to be the problem here. As Chris says, perhaps tweak the resolution of your domain?

Comment: @Chris I've got the resolution at 500. Not sure what number is actually high on this scale. The file is now attached. I'm super unsure though

Comment: @moonboots The resolution change has not seemed to help. I'll continue playing with the numbers

Comment: @ShivarIshripersadh: I just downloaded your file, changed resolution to 100 and got: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cPIkT.gif ....so what is your problem!? Or did you upload another file than that, what you tried?

Comment: @Chris That is the most recent update. My resolution was set at 500. I thought, a higher number is better. I set it to 100, and it worked. Even seeing your gif, of it working made me melt with satisfaction. I'll get to finishing it. Thank you

Comment: You are welcome